# Mixed content error google tag manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I've inserted Google Tag Manager code and still receiving mixed content error (I have no tags fired inside GTM).

I know about the other questions around here, but this seems to be another case:

This is the URL where it's loaded:
https://www.ilpasso.ro/index.php?page=cart

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your base href is set to http. Since relative links pick the protocol/hostname from the base href GTM will use the http value.

Change

```
<base href="http://www.ilpasso.ro/" />
```

to

```
<base href="https://www.ilpasso.ro/" />
```

and you should be all set.